# Add multiple metadata in video using ffmpeg command

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata

Command to add single metadata working fine

```
ffmpeg -i '/var/www/html/public/uploads/wp-video/akka.mov' -metadata kKeyContentIdentifier='com.apple.quicktime.content.identifier' '/var/www/html/public/uploads/video-thumb/updated-akka.mov'
```

Add multiple metadata command, I pass the multiple metadata tag like below

```
ffmpeg -i '/var/www/html/public/uploads/wp-video/akka.mov' -metadata kKeyContentIdentifier='com.apple.quicktime.content.identifier' -metadata kKeyStillImageTime = 'com.apple.quicktime.still-image-time' -metadata kKeySpaceQuickTimeMetadata = 'mdta' '/var/www/html/public/uploads/video-thumb/updated-akka.mov'
```

Its not working, is there any other way to pass multiple metadata in command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
ffmpeg -i "/var/www/html/public/uploads/wp-video/akka.mov" -c copy -metadata kKeyContentIdentifier="com.apple.quicktime.content.identifier" -metadata kKeyStillImageTime="com.apple.quicktime.still-image-time" -metadata kKeySpaceQuickTimeMetadata="mdta" "/var/www/html/public/uploads/video-thumb/updated-akka.mov"
```

I replaced `'` with `"`, added a `-c copy` flag and finally removed the whitespaces from the 2nd and 3rd `-metadata` declaration. I'm not quite sure if replacing `'` with `"` is necessary but I often had troubles in the past using `'` because it was read as if it was escaped instead of being a delimiter. I'm pretty sure you are not supposed to have whitespaces outside of either `'` or `"`, that's why I removed them. Omitting `-c copy` will also make ffmpeg re-encode the file with standard preset likely giving you a bad result