# ffmpeg metadata copy (all)

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata

Hope you are having a wonderful day,

I come with question related to FFMPEG and copying metadata.

So my output file got just some of metadata, but not all of them, even if my .txt contains them.

currently using -map_metadata 0:g as i read somewhere here it is supposed to copy everything. I tried few others but none are working.

I make everything in bat file so this is part of "for" loop:

`ffmpeg -i "%%A" -f ffmetadata metadata.txt -f rawvideo -y NUL`

and then

`ffmpeg -i "%%A" -f ffmetadata -i metadata.txt -c copy  -map_metadata 0:g -movflags +faststart "%output%\%%~nAtag.mov"`

Now, I get from metadata title, author, but I do not get field "description". So not ALL the data is copied. Do you know how to basically copy these metadata from file to another (absolutely all of them?

PS
`-metadata description="TESTESTTEST"`
seems to work only on mp4 files, not mov files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a non-ffmpeg solution, [exiftool](https://exiftool.org) can be used to copy metadata in MP4/Mov files with this command
`exiftool -TagsFromFile source.mp4 -All:All target.mp4`

Batch processing can be done with this command, assuming the files are the same name
`exiftool -TagsFromFile /path/to/sources/%F -All:All /path/to/targets/`

These commands creates backup files.  Add [`-overwrite_original`](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#overwrite_original) to suppress the creation of backup files.

Comment: thank you! this solution works. I would like to ask as you seem to know your jam, is it possible to read with exiftool all the metadata from 1 mov video and save it to the excel format (or txt) and then to import the same structure (excel file or txt) and save it all to the video that does not have any metadata?

Comment: I found that export to .csv is possible via:
`exiftool -r -all -csv *.mov > metadata.csv`

But what about import?

Comment: did import with ` exiftool -csv="metadata.csv" "test_NEW.mov" ` yet it does not import tag "Description", somehow in the new file description is under "Movie_more" tag and it is not recognized by QuickTime, which is main reason I am trying to make this work..
Any idea how to put tag "Decsription from the original file"

Comment: I'd suggest heading over to the [exiftool forums](https://exiftool.org/forum/) and posting there.  It's not really easy to trouble shoot a problem here.  But I'd compare the original to the new version using the command in [exiftool FAQ #3](https://exiftool.org/faq.html#Q3).  There are actually 2 or 3 `Description` locations (`ItemList`,`Keys`,`UserData`) and you might have to include that when you create the CSV file (add [`-G1`](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#G-NUM-:NUM...--groupNames) to the first command).

Comment: Thank you @StarGeek, you've been excellent help! It seems that exiftool instead of writing on tag com.apple.quicktime.title, writes just on 'title' tag, but that is not visible on QTime player (even that MediaInfo shows in title right). That quicktime is pain in the ass.

Answer (score 1):

For mov & mp4 containers, custom tags can be written if `-movflags use_metadata_tags` is added.
See Gyan [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1208273/how-to-add-new-and-non-defined-metadata-to-an-mp4-file#1208277)

Comment: thanks! there was a problem and I cannot set few tags in the same time, like 'title' and  'description' tag

Comment: @audioguy : in your example, the "metadata.txt" file is not taken into account. You have to add `-map_metadata 1` to apply your tags.

Comment: thank you @AlainA45! and do you know if I can do add specifically adobe tags? for this example: `com.apple.quicktime.author="Me", com.apple.quicktime.keywords="blah, nah", com.apple.quicktime.description="This is a Test" `  Just as here `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54248390/add-multiple-metadata-in-video-using-ffmpeg-command`   but for different type of tags?

Comment: Yes, absolutely : `ffmpeg -i INPUT -c copy -movflags use_metadata_tags -metadata com.apple.quicktime.author=Me -metadata com.apple.quicktime.keywords="blah, nah" -metadata com.apple.quicktime.description="This is a Test" -f mov OUTPUT`

Comment: yeah I did that before i think, and as it shows these informations in MediaInfo, none metadata is visible in QuickTime's Movie Inspector :(